# Intellij Idea not importing Maven Modules recursively

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am currently evaluating a switch vom Eclipse to Idea for our Java project. The project consists of >1000 Maven modules, the structure is something like follows:

```
- parent 
-- ObjectGroup1
--- business
---- business-api
---- business-impl
---- business-it
--- data
---- data-api
---- data-model
---- data-dao
-- ObjectGroup2
...
```

Each of these is a seperate Maven module with its own pom.xml.

I cloned the project to my hard drive, and from the Idea Welcome Screen, selected "Open Project". The project is detected as a maven project, however only the top most "parent" is marked as a Maven module. All others are marked as folders.
Under "File -> Project Structure" I tried to import the remaining modules. Now the level of ObjectGroups is detected as maven module but none of the underlying modules and submodules.

I learned, that I could add each Module individually by right-clicking on the pom.xml and selecting "Add as maven project", but with more than 1000 maven modules, this is not really pratically.

Is there a way to let Idea recursively search for all maven Modules and import the project correctly?
I am using Intellij Idea CE 2023.1.

Best, Patrick

Comment: IDEA should pick up your Project's structure automatically.
Are those Modules lined to one another on pom.xml level (Project Inheritance/Aggregation)?
Try opening the Project by double-clicking the root pom.xml from IDEA's "Open File or Project" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our project modules are linked to one another via profiles. I had to activate the one profile which contains all maven modules and reload all maven projects via the Maven window.
Thanks @romanv-jb for the hint!